# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 11: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

I'm using python 3.6 and this is my code:

```
import csv

with open('data1.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

And then I got this:

```
runfile('/Users/rong/Desktop/untitled0.py', wdir='/Users/rong/Desktop')
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-18-a9ca6afc41f8>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/rong/Desktop/untitled0.py', wdir='/Users/rong/Desktop')

  File "/Users/rong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 705, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/rong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/Users/rong/Desktop/untitled0.py", line 15, in <module>
    for row in reader:

  File "/Users/rong/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/codecs.py", line 321, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

I'm not sure which encoding should I use for 0x95, anyone helps plese?

Comment: when in doubt, try `latin1` or `iso-8859-1`

Comment: `cp1252` is also worth a shot

Comment: Instead of guessing, you can also (1) go back to wherever you generated the file (e.g., export from Excel?) and look at what your settings are—or just explicitly re-export as UTF-8, or (2) use `chardet` (and then verify that its output looks reasonable) to make a semi-educated guess instead of a random one.

Comment: @ChootsMagoots It's showing `line contains NULL byte` for  `latin1` and `iso-8859-1`. And for `cp1252` it's showing `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 55: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @abernert has a point, let's do more than guess.  How was the file generated?

Comment: If you don't know how to test it yourself, run this and edit the results into your question: `with open(<path to the file>, 'rb') as f: print(next(f).hex())`

Comment: @abarnert I tried to open the file in sublime and save with encoding utf-8. Problem is then the file becomes unreadable and filled with messy numbers and letters.

Comment: @sayalmondbutter When you open the file in Sublime, what encoding is Sublime using to open it? If it's the wrong one, that's just going to generate mojibake, and make it even _harder_ to recover the file. But meanwhile, go back to how you originally created the file. How did you do that? What program, what settings, etc.? (And, of course, did it all look correct in that program?)

Comment: The code @abarnert proposed resulted in invalid syntax. I got the file by just changing the extension .xlsx to .csv

Comment: did you change `<path to file>` to the path to the file and add new lines as appropriate?

Comment: I got the file from someone else in the form of a spreadsheet.

Comment: `I got the file by just changing the extension .xlsx to .csv` so, **it is not a text file**.

Comment: Open the file with excel and export it as a .csv

Comment: As far as python is concerned, simply changing the extension literally does nothing.  You could achieve the same result by importing the original `.xlsx` file.  However, a .xlsx file is not a text file, and this will result in mojibake

Comment: If you want to read a `.xlsx` file, you have to do one of two things: (1) use a Python library for `xlsx` files instead of the `csv` library, or (2) use Excel (or Google Sheets or LibreOffice or whatever) to open the file and export it as a `.csv` so your existing Python code can read it. It's not even a character set issue; the file format is just not even close to `.csv`.